# Create a Map of all the parameter names and values of a method

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I am working on REST API service and each time when exception is occured I need to show in logs params , method and class name where this exception happened. So i have singleton class with method

```
public void log(final String className,String methodName,final Map<String,String> params,final String cause) {
    final StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        result.append(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue()+" ");
    }
    log.info("\n\t\t\tClass: "+className+"\n\t\t\t Method: "+methodName+"\n\t\t\t Params: "+result.toString()+" \n\t\t\t "+"Reason: "+cause);
}
```

Example of use

```
public String checkSession(String sid) {
    final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("sid", sid);
    if (sid.isEmpty()) {
        logger.log(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "checkSession", params, " not valid session");
        return Enums.Error.WRONG_SESSION.toString();
    }
}
```

However in each method I need to initialize this map with all params. How can I write method that will return Map for all methods?

For example I have two methods

```
public String createPass(String name,String surname) {
    final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", name); 
        params.put("surname", surname); 
    }

public String checkSession(String sid) {
    final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("sid", sid);
}
```

And method that I need is something like

```
public HashMap<String,String> method(String args...){
    final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>
    for(...)
    map.put("parameter","parameterName");
}
```

Comment: Not exactly clear what you want to do, but if you want to instantiate the `params` map once why don't you make it a member variable? or instantiate it in a method, say `checkParams()` and pass it to the other methods (checkSession, createPass)?

Comment: Thank for response, i mean that i have over 30 methods and for each of them i get difference params , inside each method i initialize Map, is it any way to render function that will give all this params as agruments and return map of this elements?

Comment: If you don't mind using [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) you can try [ImmutableMap.of](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html). It allows you to do create the map in one line like `ImmutableMap.of("param1", "value1", "param2", "value2");`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do here is something like this:

```
public Map<String,String> paramsToMap(String... params){
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<params.length-1; i=i+2) {
        map.put(params[i], params[i+1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

And you call it this way:

```
public String createPass(String name, String surname) {
    final Map<String, String> params = paramsToMap("name", name, "surname", surname);
}

public String checkSession(String sid) {
    final Map<String, String> params = paramsToMap("sid", sid);
}
```

I wish we could use reflection, however the parameter names are removed at compile time and you are left with `arg0`, `arg1`, etc ... So it is not possible to  achieve what you want using reflection. You have to input the parameter names yourself.

Also as a side note, I think you would be better off using a `Map<String, Object>` and let the `log` method sort out how to print it out to the logs. Probably using `String.valueOf()`